# MySQL Get the first record in the last 10 records

Tags: mysql

in Mysql, I am trying to get the oldest record of the last 10 records.

To get the last 10 I would simply do
`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;`

to get the oldest I simply use the ASC order.

I need to first order in DESC order to get the last 10 and then order by ASC to get the first record of that array. 
which query would I use to get row number 10 in DESC order, namely, the oldest of the 10 newest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) concept:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY id 
DESC LIMIT 9, 1
```

Here, OFFSET is 9 --> that means 10th row (which will be first row in the last 10 rows when ordered back in Ascending order).

Comment: the corner case is `table` containing at least one row but fewer than 10 rows. in that case, this query won't return a row. the query in answer from @sid will return a row.

Comment: @spencer7593 this "corner case" will be extremely rare; In that case, it is better to avoid a subquery based solution. one can always write one additional query to handle this edge case, in case no data is received, but chances of hitting that would be almost zero.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya in my particular case, the last 10 comes from another query so your answer is simple and to the point. Thanks

Comment: for the benefit of future readers, in the more general case, considering there could also be a WHERE condition that limits rows, and also consider generalizing this approach to the "oldest of latest *n* rows" where *n* could be 42 or 42 million. Where the specification isn't explicit about a case (what should be returned when there are fewer than *n* rows), I think we should include a note that clarifies the interpretation of the spec. It does not matter how "rare" a case is, the behavior should be well defined, and matched to the spec. Not returning a row might satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

select only 1 using a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 ) order by id ASC LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: What if the "latest ten rows" is fewer than ten rows? Is the requirement to return the oldest of the rows found, or should no row be returned? (The query in this answer satisfies one interpretation of the specification.) +10

Comment: if rows are fewer than ten rows still this will work.. say there are only 5 rows but since the limit is 10 without offset, it will pull all records till 10

Comment: in any case, even if rows are fewer than 10, there is a 100% chance this would work

Comment: it really depends on the specification that lays out the expectation of what should be returned.  a query that doesn't return a row could also be considered "to work", if that satisfies the requirement. A more complete answer to the question posed would address both interpretations of the specification, at least mentioning other possible interpretations.

Comment: why not approach the OP then, answers here are just own opinions to provide a solution

Comment: Because this is an *answer* to a question that was asked. The question is very general: "get the oldest of the last *n* records".  When giving an *answer* to the question, we should make it clear what question is being answered. A future reader looking for an answer to the same question should be able to find a good answer, not just a "try this"

Comment: the question is very specific - to return the 1st row of the last 10 rows

Comment: no, the question is *not* specific, because there is no specification as to what should be returned if there are less than 10 rows. the value of *n* doesn't make the question specific. saying the question is specific makes it seem like we would also ask other specific questions:     "how to return the 1st row of the last 11 rows", "how to return the 1st row of the last 12 rows", ... "how to return the 1st row of the last 99 rows" .  All of those questions are unspecific in the same way as the question asked here was. The value of *n* doesn't make the question *specific*.

Comment: The query in this answer satisfies on interpretation of the requirement. The speciifc-ation could say "if there is more than zero rows and fewer than ten rows, then return the oldest of the available rows."  That would be specific-ation. Alternatively, the spec could say "if there are fewer than ten rows, then don't return a row." Again, that would be a specific-ation. The query in this answer "works" for one of those specific-ations but not the other.