# This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME sub-query' while extracting 6th largest salary

Tags: mysql

I wrote Mysql query which extract 6th largest salary from the employee table. I went through other stack overflow links also please don't make this as duplicate.

My query is how to pass the limit inside subquery.

Below code is which is of inner join is working fine

```
select e1.first_name,e1.salary 
from employees e1  
inner join (select employee_id 
            from employees  
            order by salary desc limit 6) as e2  
        on e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id  
order by salary asc limit 1;

| first_name | salary |
+------------+--------+
| Barby      | 164588 |
```

When I wrote in subquery while passing limit inside subquery throwing error

```
select first_name,salary 
from employees 
where employee_id in (select employee_id 
                      from employees  
                      order by salary desc **limit 6** ) 
order by salary desc limit 6;

| first_name | salary |
+------------+--------+
| Jacklyn    | 166976 |
| Carissa    | 166765 |
| Riley      | 166569 |
| Lauren     | 166016 |
| Lucy       | 165660 |
| Barby      | 164588 |
```

Desired out is below I want to write in subquery not with Joins

```
| first_name | salary |
+------------+--------+
| Barby      | 164588 |
```

Comment: Which MySQL version? -> `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: *"Desired out is below I want to write in subquery not with Joins"* is that a [homework/job interview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) restriction or do you think JOINs are from the SQL anti performance devil?

Comment: Your first approach using `JOIN` would be having better performance than using `IN(...)`; so why do you want to go down that road even.. Also, as of now, MySQL does not support using `LIMIT ..` clause inside a subquery that is used in the `IN` clause.

Comment: Also, it definitely looks like your question is duplicate of:  [MySQL Get the first record in the last 10 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628862/mysql-get-the-first-record-in-the-last-10-records)

Comment: Most likely your are right @MadhurBhaiya ,  the topicstarter means to make the query more complex then it has to.

Comment: | VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 |

Comment: SELECT first_name,salary FROM employees  ORDER BY salary  DESC LIMIT 5, 1;

Comment: select e1.first_name,e1.salary from employees e1  INNER JOIN (select employee_id from employees  order by salary desc limit 6) as e2  on e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id  order by salary asc limit 1;